# Hiding Fields on Edit Form in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, schema

I was wondering if there's a way to hide fields on the edit form on one view but have them display on another?

Right now I am using:

```
  <FieldRef ID="{EF8477CA-D07E-4368-9359-5A33A9E0222C}" Name="Requester" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE"/>
```

this in my contentType, but I'm pretty sure this will hide it throughout the whole site, is there a way to hide it just at specific points so it's still visible on some edit pages but not on others?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not hiding the Field in the Edit form, but define a custom form in your List Definition and hiding it from that one.

In the list definition scheema add this in your forms element:

```
  <Form Type="EditForm"
        Url="CustomNewForm.aspx"
        SetupPath="pages\form.aspx"
        WebPartZoneID="Main" />
```

After deploying the list, open the form generated and simply hide the  containing the field using css display:none;

Finally, use the custom form where ever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This can help: [Showing or hiding form fields based on membership in a SharePoint group](http://spjsblog.com/2009/09/20/showing-or-hiding-list-fields-based-on-membership-in-a-sharepoint-group/)